# Need to pass multiple variables to payload variables

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.6

I am trying to pass multiple variables to payload using format & +str(Var)+ but I am not getting the expected output. I have the hostnames in a file & get a password as input and want to pass it to the payload.

I am getting an error related to `"Error while parsing JSON payload or an incompatible argument type for the requested resource"`

```
for x in content:
        url='https://url/a/b/c/{}'.format(x.strip())
        payload=('{{"ip-address": "x.x.x.x","user-name": "john","password": "'+ str(Pass) +'","db-name": "'+ str(x.strip()) +'","service-name": "y","port": "y","connection-string": "y"}}')
        response = req.post(url,json=payload,headers=add_cookie,verify=False)


======================

for x in content:
        url='https://url/a/b/c/{}'.format(x.strip())
        payload={"ip-address": "x.x.x.x","user-name": "john","password": "{}","db-name": "{}","service-name": "y","port": "y","connection-string": "y"}.format(Pass, x.strip())
        response = req.post(url,json=payload,headers=add_cookie,verify=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In first part your payload is a string and not a dict, it should be

```
payload={"ip-address": "x.x.x.x","user-name": "john","password": str(Pass),"db-name": str(x.strip()),"service-name": "y","port": "y","connection-string": "y"}
```

In the second one you're using the format function on a dict type which is wrong.

Comment: The variable is not replaced. "+  str(Pass) +"  & "+ str(x.strip()) +"  stringis passed abruptly with taking the passed value.